# label and the felder are not center in the rows

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a problem with your form, how can I put the text and the elements at the same distance, e.g. show the label next to the fields, they are not on the same line, i.e. not centered on the line,
pls see pic on the Link
[My Form](https://pasteboard.co/KfHpw7a.jpg)

I have a problem with your form, how can I put the text and the elements at the same distance, e.g. show the label next to the fields, they are not on the same line, i.e. not centered on the line,
pls see pic on the Link
[My Form](https://pasteboard.co/KfHpw7a.jpg)

I have a problem with your form, how can I put the text and the elements at the same distance, e.g. show the label next to the fields, they are not on the same line, i.e. not centered on the line,
pls see pic on the Link
[My Form](https://pasteboard.co/KfHpw7a.jpg)

```css
body{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
background-color: #FFBB00;
}
.container{
   
   width: 40%;
   margin: 4% auto;
   padding: 50px;
   background-color: #fff;
   border-radius: 15px;
   box-shadow: #ccc 0 0  10px 0; /* للظل لحتى يطلع متناسب */ 
}
.title h1{
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 28px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
.title h1::after{
content: "";
width: 30%;
height: 3px;
background-color: #FFBB00;
position: absolute;
top: 110%;
left: 35%;
}


.inputFeld{

   padding: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
   border-radius:4px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.inputFeld:focus{

background-color: #FFBB00;  ;
}
/*  */
.parent-line{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
   align-content: center;
   padding: 15px;

}

.parent-line .line-link{
   display: flex;
   flex: 1;

}

.parent-line .line-right{
 flex: 1;
 display: flex;

   }




   .parent-one-line{
      padding: 15px;
   }

      .container .line label{
         display: inline-block;
         width: 150px;
         text-align: left;
      }

/*  */



.btn{
   padding: 19px 10px;
   margin-bottom: 500px;

   background-color: #000;
   color: #fff;
   border: none;
   float: right;
   cursor: pointer;
   width: 100%;
}
.btn:hover{
   background-color: #FFBB00;
   color: #000;
}

.checken{
   padding: 10px;
}
.select{
   padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<style>
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
   </style>
   
<body>
   
<section class="container">
   <dic class="title"><h1>ITEMS VERLINKEN </h1></dic>
   <form action="">

      <!--  -->
<div class="parent-line">
   <div class="line-link">
            <div class="line"> <label class="" for=""> Link URL   </label> <input class="inputFeld" type="text" name="" id="" >  </div>
      </div>
   
   <div class="line-right">
            <div class="line"> <label for=""> +articleNum+ </label> <input class="inputFeld" type="text" name="" id="" >   </div>
      
   </div>
</div>

      <!--  -->



      <div class="parent-line">


         <div class="line-link">
            <div class="line"> <label for=""> Full PDF name  </label>  <input class="inputFeld" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Example: test.pdf ">
             </div>
   
            </div>   


            <div class="line-right">

            <div class="line"> <label for=""> Full PDF Links </label> 
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" id="">  
                </div>   
   
            </div>   
   
         </div>

         <!--  -->

         <div class="parent-line">
   
               <div class="line-link">
               <div class="line"> <label for=""> PDF Width in mm</label> 
               <input class="inputFeld" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Example: 212" size="4"> 
               </div> 
               </div> 
   
               <div class="line-right">
               <div class="line"> <label for=""> PDF Height in mm</label> 
               <input class="inputFeld" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Example: 290 " size="4"> 
      
               </div>         
               </div>
   
            </div>


         <!--  -->


         <div class="parent-line">
   
   
                  <div class="line-link">
                     <div class="line"> 
                     <label for=""> Border around links</label> 
                           <select class="select" name="" id="">
                           <option value="">No</option>
                           <option value="">Yes</option>
                           </select> 
                     </div>
   
                  </div>         
               
                  <div class="line-right">
                  <div class="line"> <label for=""> Border(RGB):</label>
                  <input class="inputFeld" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="R" size="1">  
                  <input class="inputFeld" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="G" size="1" > 
                  <input class="inputFeld" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="B"  size="1"> 
                 </div>
                  </div>
   
         </div>

      <!--  -->

               <div class="parent-line">
               <div class="line-link">
               <div class="line">
                <label for=""> Border Width(mm)</label> <select class="select" name="" id="">
               <option value="">0</option>
               </select>
               </div>
               </div>
   
   
               <div class="line-right">
               <div class="line">
               <label for="">Margin top (mm)</label> <select class="select" name="" id="">
                  <option value="">0</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               </div>       
   
   
               </div>



<!--  -->





         <div class="parent-one-line">
          <div class="line"> <label for=""> Save settings:  </label> <input class="inputFeld" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Example: Customer1 "> 
         <h5>Leave empty to prevent saving.</h5>
         </div>
        
         <input class="btn" type="button" value="Start">
      

         </div>   


   </form>
</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `align-items:center` to

```
.parent-line .line-right{
 flex: 1;
 display: flex;
}
```

and increase/decrease input text height/font size to match the center.